# First user input is ignored by mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables in database. countries(country_name,country_code), users(username,email,password) and visited(country_name,username,rating). country_name and username are foreign keys in visited and they must be unique, for example if there is row:

'France'| 'User' | 5

if user want's to insert row with same values of foreign key:

'France'|'User'| 3

It should just update rating, so result should be this:

'France'|'User'| 3

I tried to do it like this, but when new user inserts new country it doesn't do anything, it works fine after user already made one insert that got ignored, next inserts are good.
So for example if inputs are:

'Croatia'|'User'| 1

'Cambodia'|'User'| 3

Database would look like this:

'Cambodia'|'User'| 3

this is my php file:

```
<?php  
include "connection.php";


if(isset($_POST['country']) && isset($_POST['ratings']) && isset($_POST['username'])){
  $country= $_POST['country'];
  $ratings = $_POST['ratings'];
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];
  $result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO visited(country_name,rate,username) 
             VALUES('".$country."', '".$ratings."', '".$username."')
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
             country_name= '".$country."',
             username='".$username."',
             rate='".$ratings."'");

echo "$country";
echo "$ratings";
echo "$username";


 }
 else{
     echo "Error";
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You got ON DUPLICATE wrong :

```
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO visited(country_name,rate,username) 
             VALUES('".$country."', '".$ratings."', '".$username."')
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
             country_name= '".$country."',
             username='".$username."',
             rate='".$ratings."'");
```

It should be:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO visited(country_name,rate,username) 
             VALUES('".$country."', '".$ratings."', '".$username."')
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
             rate='".$ratings."'");
```

Also `visited` table must has `country_name,username` together as a Primary key , right ?

Comment: Thank you! It works.It is realtion many to many so country_name and username are foreign keys. I made constraint so they must be unique combination.